# Possible to specify directory path with a wildcard?

Tags: c#, .net, path

I have the following piece of code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
{
    // whatever
}
```

That gets files from a specific directory.  Would it be possible to match directories using a wildcard?  For example:

```
c:\test\di*
```

would match all files in the directories:

```
c:\test\dictionary\
c:\test\directory\
c:\test\dig\
```

I saw that you can pass a file filter to the GetFiles method, but that applies to files only, not directory names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx) for this which allows you to specify a search pattern or if you need to specify search options there's [another overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314.aspx):

```
foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "di*"))
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I believe that is a file filter and does not allow for use of wildcards when specifying the directory.  Wouldn't your example only get files that start with `di` in a specific directory.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, no, it works with directory names perfectly fine. Try the example I posted: `Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\test", "di*"))` will match all the directories you have shown in your question.

Comment: Ahh, I was looking at `GetFiles` instead of `GetDirectories`.  Thanks!