# How to scan a directory with wildcard with a specific subdirectory

Tags: c#, search, directory, wildcard

I was wondering what would be a good way to scan a directory that has characters you are not sure of.

For example, I want to scan

> C:\Program\Version2.*\Files

Meaning

- The folder is located in `C:\Program`
- `Version2.*` could be anything like `Version2.33`, `Version2.1`, etc.
- That folder has a folder named `Files` in it

I know that I could do something like `foreach (directory) if contains("Version2.")`, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing so.

Comment: Have you tried the [Directory.GetFiles function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)? I'm not sure if that would include several directories, but it has `*` as wildcard

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286477/possible-to-specify-directory-path-with-a-wildcard

Comment: @Default, that answer is useful, when wildcard at the end of the path, not in the middle as seem to be in this question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are right, I noticed that detail after I suggested the "duplicate" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Directory.EnumerateDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383572(v=vs.100).aspx)  accepts search pattern. So enumerate parent that has wildcard and than enumerate the rest:

```
  var directories = 
    Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Program\", "Version2.*")
     .SelectMany(parent => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parent,"Files"))
```

Note: if path can contain wildcards on any level - simply normalize path and split by "\", than collect folders level by level.

Comment: Is there a reason to use EnumerateDirectories instead of GetDirectories?

Comment: @Default EnumerateDirectories uses lazy evaluation, so may be faster for large number of files/folders (check remarks section of MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383572(v=vs.100).aspx) )

Comment: This seem to best fit what I am currently looking for (:
I will give it a try soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"C:\\Program\\Version 2(.*)\\Files(.*)");

var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Program", "*", 
                                                 SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                                .Where(d => pattern.IsMatch(d));
```

Comment: +1. May work, but likely to find way more directoies - will require additional filtering later.