# Searching with System.IO.Directory.GetFiles and wildcards in path

Tags: c#

I have a curious problem in a C#-program.
I have some local folderpaths like

```
"C:\test\AB_Systems\ELEGANCE\CB-DOC\live\M7-091.249.99.XX.01\extobjects".
```

Now i want to search for PDF-files in the subfolder called "extobjects".
Unfortunately there are many subfolders in the folder "live", which got a subfolder called "extobjects", so i thought it would be better to use a wildcard in the searchpath like that:

```
"C:\test\AB_Systems\ELEGANCE\CB-DOC\live\*\extobjects"
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there a way do do this?

Comment: Sure, start at live, and for each directory, if theres an extobjects, look in there..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scan a directory with wildcard with a specific subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815564/how-to-scan-a-directory-with-wildcard-with-a-specific-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static FileInfo[] findFile(String whereToSearch, String searchFor , String mode)
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = null;
        if (mode.Equals(""))
            mode = "s";

        if (searchFor.Equals(""))
            searchFor = "*";

        if (mode.Equals("r") || mode.Equals("recursive"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(whereToSearch);
            files = dir.EnumerateFiles(searchFor, searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }

        if (mode.Equals("s") || mode.Equals("specific"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(whereToSearch);
            files = dir.EnumerateFiles(searchFor, searchOption: SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }

        if (files != null) return files.ToArray<FileInfo>();
        else return null;
    }
```

That's an example how to do it.

It's important to say that only the filename can contain a wildcard pattern like *. The Path can be given as where to start the search and by giving **searchOption: searchOption.AllDirectories** as an argument it will go through all sub-directories of the entry path.

You will receive an Array of FileInfo which objects that contain the the path and more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq like this:

```
var files = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\test\AB_Systems\ELEGANCE\CB-DOC\live", "extobjects", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .SelectMany(x => Directory.EnumerateFiles(x, "*pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose a solution exactly what BugFinder proposed, you could optimize the following foreach-loop into a LINQ query if your .NET target supports it.

```
        // Itterate subdirectories of the live folder
        foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\test\AB_Systems\ELEGANCE\CB-DOC\live"))
        {
            // Check if path to extobjects exists
            var extObjects = Path.Combine(subDir, "extobjects");
            if (Directory.Exists(extObjects))
            {
                var pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(extObjects, "*").Where(x=>x.EndsWith(".pdf"));
                // Do something with the pdf file paths
            }
        }
```