# Identify whether a subfolder starting with a certain string exists or not

Tags: c#

I want to find out if a certain folder has subfolders starting with a particular name.

For Eg.

In my C:\Test folder, I have folders like GUI, TCP, PLC, PLC_1, PLC_2... PLC_n.

I may or may not have PLC_ folders. I want to check whether those folders exist or not. And if they exist I want to extract the names of all such folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7286508/61470

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ [**this edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4798621) is just a cosmetic fix on my [**previously accepted one**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4798388) - so.... thanks for your rejection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string[] plcDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Test", "PLC*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
if(plcDirs.Any())
{
    // ...
}
```

If there are many sub-directories it is more efficient to use the deferred executed [`EnumerateDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which does not need to load all into memory before it can start processing:

```
var plcDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\Test", "PLC*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

MSDN:

> The EnumerateDirectories and GetDirectories methods differ as follows:
>   When you use EnumerateDirectories, you can start enumerating the
>   collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you
>   use GetDirectories, you must wait for the whole array of names to be
>   returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and directories, EnumerateDirectories can be
>   more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through subfolders by:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subfolders = directory.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo subfolder in subfolders) 
{
    //TODO: add logic here for your check. e.g.
    if (subfolder.name.StartsWith(somestring)) 
    {
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following, you can search folder and subfolders using searchpattern.  It is most reliable, as GetAll sometimes fails when appropriate permissions is not correct.

[Get all files and directories in specific path fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6061957/1662973)

Answer (score 0):

If the name pattern of the subdirectories to be found is more complicated, you can use Regex:

```
var subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Test")
                       .Where(dir => Regex.IsMatch(dir, @"PLC_\d+"));
```