# How to getFiles from a directory path that uses wildcards

Tags: c#

This question is similar:
[Possible to specify directory path with a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286477/possible-to-specify-directory-path-with-a-wildcard)

However in my case I want to obtain all files from every single folder named 'data' that is a first child of all folders in my directory.

Hypothetically what I would need is the following:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory + "\\Share\\*\\data");
```

*'directory' is simply a string of the directory path

Wildcards are not accepted in both GetFiles and GetDirectories methods and it is my understanding, they must be used as filters as a second parameter (both these methods have that overload). However in the GetFiles case, it is specifically to filter **files** and not directories, and in the GetDirectories case, it is giving me the same error, as if the filter was only applicable on the lowest level directories (or something of the sort).

> I could do this with multiple calls to GetDirectories and GetFiles in
>   a loop, but I'd rather find a more
>   elegant solution. (i.e. What I want to avoid:: Get all directories
>   under my directory\Share, loop through and add get all files for each
>   \data directory of those, agglomerate all of that into a list of
>   strings for my file names etc...)

**EDIT - SOLUTION::** Actually @Steve Wong pointed me towards the solution I went with (hopefully regexes aren't a big no-no):

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\\" + directory + @"\\Share\\.*\\data\\.*\.xml$");

List<string> files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(connect + "\\Share","*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path)).ToList();
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't think there is any other way than to loop through. Extract it out to a method and forget about it... You say it's 'heavier' but any other implementation is likely to do just that, only you wouldn't be seeing it directly.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right, I asked around a bit and I'm getting to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
string rootDirectory = directory + "\\Share\\";
var files = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(
      (directoryPath) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(Path.GetFileName(directoryPath), "Data") == 0).SelectMany(
      (directoryPath) => Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*"));
```

The Where clause will return all folder paths that end with a "Data/data" folder, and then the SelectMany returns all files in those folders.

Comment: I'm tempted to use this, however the SelectMany does the operation on iteration, meaning while it would now be coded on a single line, it still does the loop through the originally found directories. (And here I'm not sure but I get the feeling this is actually less performant in that in gets all files \\*\\* and then returns those that match the path \\*\data)    I think @DrewJordan is right in that there is no way around this behavior - and for code clarity I think I'll just code the foreach loop. I did ask for a simply more elegant solution though, and in this regards I will give a +1 :)