# Check if a folder exists with only a part of the name in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a code to create folders with two Textboxes.

- Textbox1 - customer number (XXXX).
- Textbox2 - customer name.

I would like to be able to check if the customer number exists before creating the folder.
The newly created folder will be the combination of the two Textboxes (this is already solved).
I just need to be able to determine if the folder exists only with the customer number, as it is probably created with (customer number + customer name).

Current working code:

```
    {
        string no = textBox1.Text;
        string client = textBox2.Text;
        string carpeta = @"C:\" + no + " " + client;
        string sourcePath = @"C:\main";
        string destinationPath = @"C:\" + no + " " + client;
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();

        try
        {
            
                if (Directory.Exists(carpeta))
                {
                    DialogResult y;
                    y = MessageBox.Show("Folder already exists\nDo you want to open it?", "AE.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    if (y == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\" + no + " " + client);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogResult x;
                    x = MessageBox.Show("The folder doesn't exist\nWant to create a folder?." + "\n" + no + " " + client, "AE.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    if (x == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta);
                        FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcePath, destinationPath, UIOption.AllDialogs);
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\" + no + " " + client);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Close();
                    }
                }              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to specify directory path with a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286477/possible-to-specify-directory-path-with-a-wildcard)

Comment: Assuming the customer number and name are separated by a space, you may use `bool exists = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir, $"{customerNumber} *").Any();`

Comment: Side note: C# has a [built-in way to combine parts of a path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) so there is no need to use `string +` operations and have to deal with missing or extra path separator slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\",  txtTextBox.Text + "*");
```

this will only get directrories starting with the desired Text

Edit: This is only a good solution if the customer number has fixed places (in you exaple 4 from 0000-9999)

[Microsoft Documentation - check example below](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0)

Comment: `txtTextBox.Text + "*"` is bad. If `txtTextBox.Text` is 1, for example, it will match "1 name", "123 name", "1534653 name", etc.

Comment: That is correct if the number does not have a fixed format. In the example given it should be 4 places (0000-9999). If it is not the case the result has to be parsed - another / better solution may then be used

Answer (score 1):

You could also each time you need the folder just do that:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var username = "someuser";
        var usernumber = "ABC123";
        var mainDirectory = @"C:\Path\To\The\Main\Dir";
        var pathToTheUserDirectory = Path.Combine(mainDirectory, $"{username}-{usernumber}");

        // This line will create the directory if not exist or take the existing directory.
        var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToTheUserDirectory);

        var directoryPath = directoryInfo.FullName;

        // ...  
        // or
        // directoryInfo.Delete(recursive: true);
    }
```